# NSFetchedResultsController with section names

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Scenario:

I have an expense tracking iOS Application and I am storing expenses from a expense detail view controller into a table view (with fetched results controller) that shows the list of expenses along with the category and amount and date. I do have a date attribute in my entity "Money" which is a parent entity for either an expense or an income.

My Question:

What I want is to basically categorize my expenses/incomes for a given week, a month, or year and display it as the section header title for example : (Oct 1- Oct 7, 2012) and it shows expenses/incomes amount and related stuff according to that particular week. Two buttons are provided in that view, if I would press the right button, it will increment the week by a week (Oct 1- Oct 7, 2012 now shows Oct8 - Oct 15, 2012) and similarly the left button would decrement the week by a week. I have two segment controls in the view as well. What I want to do is press the segment control which says "weekly" and if I press another segment which says "category" - how would I filter out my expenses/incomes per week based on category ?

I want to display two sections in my table view (one which shows the date for expenses and another to show the date for incomes in format (Oct1,2012 - Oct7, 2012)). How would I achieve this? I have written some pseudo code and if anybody can tell me how would I accomplish the above, that would be great.

EDIT - FETCH CONTROLLER

```
- (void)userDidSelectStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{    
    AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Money" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];

    //Here you create the predicate that filters the results to only show the ones with the selected date
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
     [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.

    NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor3 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cat" ascending:YES];

    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, sortDescriptor3, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];

    if(_fetchedResultsController)
    {
          [_fetchedResultsController release]; _fetchedResultsController = nil;

    }
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"type" cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *anyError = nil;

    if(![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&anyError])
    {
        NSLog(@"error fetching:%@", anyError);
    }

    [sortDescriptor1 release];
    [sortDescriptor2 release];
    [sortDescriptor3 release];

    [fetchRequest release];

     //Finally you tell the tableView to reload it's data, it will then ask your NEW FRC for the new data
    [self.dashBoardTblView reloadData];

}
```

EDIT - Fetch Controller Delegate Methods

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
{
     [self.dashBoardTblView beginUpdates];

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

   switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.dashBoardTblView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.dashBoardTblView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
   }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

        [self.dashBoardTblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

        [self.dashBoardTblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:

        [self.dashBoardTblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.dashBoardTblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    {
        [self.dashBoardTblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }
  }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.dashBoardTblView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To group the "Expense"/"Income" objects into different sections, you need to add a `type` attribute to the `Money` entity, for example a `Integer` attribute that is `0` for expenses and `1` for incomes.

To sort the table view sections by type (expense/income), use `type` as *first* sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *s1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
```

To sort the entries within each section by date, use `date` as *second* sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *s2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:s1, s2, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Finally, to group the table view into sections by category, use `type` as `sectionNameKeyPath`:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
   [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                       managedObjectContext:context
                                         sectionNameKeyPath:type
                                                  cacheName:nil];
```

This should give 2 sections, with all expenses in the first section and all incomes in the second section.

Now for the section headers you have to implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` (I hope that I get this right):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    Money *money = [[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0]; // The first object in this section
    NSNumber *type = money.type;
    if (type.intValue == 0) {
        // Create and return header view for "expense" section.

    } else {
        // Create and return header view for "incomes" section.

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted my section names to show me the the current week (dates) and the rows would show the category names.

Comment: @AngadManchanda: Then I did not understand your question correctly. You said you wanted two sections (one for expenses and one for incomes). - Perhaps you can show an example how the table should look like.

Comment: Exactly i want two sections. One section with red color that would have a header for current week (date like Oct1, 2012 - Oct 7, 2012 - that's section header) and the rows would be the categories and shows expense amount. Similarly, another section with green in color showing current week as the section header and rows displaying categories with income amount. The attribute "cat" is in "Money" entity which is a parent entity for "Expense" and "Income" entity. Now, is it clear? Can you help?

Comment: @AngadManchanda: OK. But you need some attribute in the "Money" entity that is for example `0` for expenses and `1` for incomes. Otherwise the fetch request can not group by the type.

Comment: See I posted a sample screenshot. How would i accomplish that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19357/discussion-between-martin-r-and-angad-manchanda)

Comment: I have accepted your answer but the last part didn't work at all. Section header is not working and I am not even getting two sections, even if I am adding an expense data and an income data.

Comment: I know the problem is that I am not using "type" attribute anywhere else. Perhaps, I need to use it when I am adding new data to my tableview which is a mixture of expense and income. This screenshot above is another view which will display expense and income separately based on weeks, months and categorized by vendor, category and stuff. I have added the code for my section header, which only displays 0. I am pretty sure I have to use the "type" attribute somewhere else too otherwise how it would know what's the type? But where? When I add new expense/income data?

Comment: @AngadManchanda: Continuing in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19357/discussion-between-martin-r-and-angad-manchanda

Comment: Are you there to help buddy?

Comment: @AngadManchanda: Continuing in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19357/discussion-between-martin-r-and-angad-manchanda

Comment: can you please look at this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410109/display-nsdates-in-terms-of-months