# How to get previous and next month in calendar-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calendar

I am trying to get previous and next month by click on button but this has changed my year, not month.

I am trying it from using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410109/how-do-i-implement-previous-next-month-buttons-and-show-dates-for-current-month) but it is in Objective-C.

```
func firstDateOfMonth() {
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)
    let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    print(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth)) // 2015-11-01
}

func lastDateOfMonth() {
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
    
    let month = components.month
    let year = components.year
    
    let startOfMonth1 = ("01-\(month)-\(year)")
    
    var startOfMonth : NSDate?
    var lengthOfMonth : NSTimeInterval = 0
    calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Month, startDate: &startOfMonth, interval: &lengthOfMonth, forDate: date)
    let endOfMonth = startOfMonth!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(lengthOfMonth - 1)
    print(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(endOfMonth))
}

func monthCalculation() {
    firstDateOfMonth()
    lastDateOfMonth()
}

@IBAction func previousMonthBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let componen = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
    componen.month = -1
    self.date = calendar.dateFromComponents(componen)!
    print(self.date)
}

@IBAction func nextMonthBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

So how to do it for both previous and next month?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try like this.

**To get date of next month.**

**Swift 3 and Swift 4**

```
let nextMonth = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: Date())
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
let nextMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

**To get date of previous month.**

**Swift 3**

```
let previousMonth = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
let previousMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

**Note:** To get date of next and previous month I have used todays date, you can use date from which you want next and previous month date, just change `NSDate()` with your `NSDate` object.

**Edit:** For continues traveling of next and previous months you need to store one date object currentDate and when you try to get next and previous month use that date object and update it.

*For next month.*

```
let currentDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: currentDate, options: [])
```

*For previous month.*

```
let currentDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: currentDate, options: [])
```

**You can also use extension that will make thing easy.**

**Swift 3**

```
extension Date {
    func getNextMonth() -> Date? {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: self)
    }

    func getPreviousMonth() -> Date? {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self)
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
extension NSDate {
    func getNextMonth() -> NSDate?{
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: self, options: [])
    }

    func getPreviousMonth() -> NSDate?{
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: self, options: [])
    }
}
```

Now just get date from currentDate.

```
currentDate = currentDate.getNextMonth()
currentDate = currentDate.getPreviousMonth()
```

Comment: Swift 3.0.2, NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date)

Comment: **How to handle range in swift3** .          `calendar.range(.Month, startDate: &startOfMonth, interval: &lengthOfMonth, forDate: date )` .             **Error is > Extra argument 'forDate' in call**

Comment: @iDeveloper Try like this `calendar.range(of: .month, start: &startOfMonth, interval: &lengthOfMonth, for: date)`

Comment: @Jerland2 Have you tried answer just saying it without try. The answer you are looking is perfect way to add value in any date. But still you can clear your doubt. Please check this image of playground that will clear your thought. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9rh.png Check the output after subtracting one month from date March 30 it will give feb 28. Please next time before posting any comment once verified that what you thinking is correct or not

Answer (score 3):

Will add here in case people need next month as well. This works for any date:

**Swift 5.1 or later • Xcode 11 or later**

---

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    
    var year: Int {
        Calendar.iso8601.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    
    var lastDateOfPreviousMonth: Date? {
        DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: year, month: month, day: 0).date
    }
    var previousMonth: Int {
        lastDateOfPreviousMonth?.month ?? 0
    }
    
    var firstDateOfMonth: Date? {
        DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: year, month: month).date
    }
    var month: Int {
        Calendar.iso8601.component(.month, from: self)
    }

    var firstDateOfFollowingMonth: Date? {
        DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: year, month: month+1).date
    }
    var followingMonth: Int {
        firstDateOfFollowingMonth?.month ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().lastDateOfPreviousMonth    //  "Feb 28, 2022 at 12:00 AM"
Date().previousMonth              //  2

Date().firstDateOfMonth           //  "Mar 1, 2022 at 12:00 AM"
Date().month                      //  3

Date().firstDateOfFollowingMonth  // "Apr 1, 2022 at 12:00 AM"
Date().followingMonth             //  4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentDate = NSDate()

func nextMonth() -> NSDate {
    let nextDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: currentDate, options: [])!
    currentDate = nextDate
    return nextDate
}

print(nextMonth()) // 2016-11-01 20:11:15 +0000
print(nextMonth()) // 2016-12-01 21:11:15 +0000
print(nextMonth()) // 2017-01-01 21:11:15 +0000
```

Comment: Work perfect for nextMonth. what about previous month

Comment: @iDeveloper just change `value` in the function to `-1`

Comment: Sir what is the logic behind this **currentDate = nextDate**

Comment: We need to save the date, which we will use for the next call function

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
let previousYear = currentYear + 1
let nextYear = currentYear + 1
print("\(previousYear)->\(currentYear)->\(nextYear)")

Output:
2018->2019->2020
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: the op looking for answer in month

Comment: I wonder how adding 1 year to the current date would result in previous year kkkkk

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) library:

```
let date = Date()
let nextMonthDate = date.nextMonth(at: .auto)
let prevMonthDate = date.prevMonth(at: .auto)
```

You can use `.start` and `.end` instead of `.auto`. Look at the info about `nextMonth` for example:

> when `.auto` evaluated date is calculated by adding one month to the current date.
>
> If you pass `.start` result date is the first day of the next month (at 00:00:00).
>
> If you pass `.end` result date is the last day of the next month (at 23:59:59).

The library also contains `prevWeek`/`nextWeek` and many other useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet to get any previous year or month date in Swift

```
private func getPreviousDate(monthOrYear: String, numberOfMonthOrYear: Int, dateFormat: String) -> String{
    var date : Date
    if(monthOrYear.lowercased().contains("month")){
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -numberOfMonthOrYear, to: Date())!
    } else {
         date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -numberOfMonthOrYear, to: Date())!
    }
    return dateFormatter(dateFormat: dateFormat, date:date)
}

func dateFormatter (dateFormat: String, date: Date) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```